# Flink - How to set dynamic path for Flink Checkpoints

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

**We are triggering a Flink REST API for checkpoints and we are able to generate the AVRO successfully**

```
 /jobs/:jobid/checkpoints POST will trigger a checkpoint
```

**Want to set the path dynamically for flink checkpoints**
**Do we have any REST APIs or Java client to set the path dynamically for the flink checkpoints?**

Flink Version - 1.17